# Anythingslider problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

i'm using the AnythingSlider, but when i only got 1 item in the slider i get a error saying "'base.$navLinks' is null or not an object" on line 149, you can see the code here: http://pastebin.com/K7EaiFuT, can anyone see what the problem is? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a slider with only one page? That's not a slider: that's just static content!

If you have a case in which you sometimes have pages, and sometimes dont', can't you just only call the `.anythingSlider()` function if you actually need to?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in the [latest version](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-1-4/) of Anything Slider.